# codesign_allocate: can't allocate code signature data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, code-signing

I want to sign my OSX app, but getting this error, any idea?

```
fatal error: codesign_allocate: can't allocate code signature data for: 
            /...../X.app/Contents/Frameworks/libtiff.5.dylib
 (for architecture x86_64) 

because larger updated load commands do not fit (the program must be relinked using a larger -headerpad value)

                /..../Products/Debug/X.app: 

the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
In subcomponent: /..../Products/Debug/X.app/Contents/Frameworks/libtiff.5.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this error if you build your app on mac with different architecture(ex x86_64) and try to codesign that app on different architechture machine(ex i386).

Solution is to build and codesign on same machine.